# Elasticsearch Query : not full results when asking just one word

Tags: elasticsearch

for testing purpose I setup an index with just 26 records containing all products with some form of canister (German: Kanister).

When I am search for "Kanister 20 Liter"  I am getting 22 results.
When I am search for "Kanister" I am getting 10 results.

```
`  "query": {
       "bool": {
        "should": [
              { 
                      "multi_match": {
                                      "query": "'.$search_term.'",
                                        "fields": [
                                        "NameA^100",
                                        "NameB^50",        
                                        "PartNumber"  ],
                                        
                                        "operator": "or",
                                        "type": "cross_fields"
                                  }                           
                   }                                                      
           ]  // Ende Should  
       }                
        },  
  "sort": [ { "_score": { "order": "desc" } } ]         `
```

My expectation would be, that I am getting more results if I am not search very specific.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the default operator "or", searching for more words, i.e. `Kanister 20 Liter` will return more results than searching for just a single word, i.e. `Kanister`, because the query would search for

```
Kanister OR 20 OR Liter
```

which obviously would match more documents than just `Kanister`.

If you want to get less results the more query terms you provide, you need to change `operator` to `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: Yes, but at the moment (while testing) all records in the database contains the word "Kanister" . I am populating the index with a SQL Query using "like "%Kanister%""

So,  this cannot be the reason....

Comment: Oh, so you expect more results with `Kanister` than `Kanister 20 Liter`? Do you mind providing a gist with your sample 26 documents as well as the index mapping you're using?